# How do I make my form POST stripe token to next page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments, dom-events

I've setup my stripe Elements form (literally just copied it from the docs) and I am now stuck at the tokenizing part.

I need to send the token that's been generated to the next page so that I can create a charge in Stripe.

Form method is set to `POST`.

Here's my code https://jsfiddle.net/itsjustarbs/jbkasker/1/

I don't know how to write Javascript but I have a fair idea of reading code.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The Stripe documentation shows how to do it.

Comment: Obviously i know that i been through the docs. Followed their instructions and it still wont work

Comment: Can you post an MCVE here, emphasis on the Minimal part. There's way too much stuff in the fiddle.

Comment: And it's usually unnecessary to use jsfiddle to post code, SO has [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I took your code and ran it on my server, and it seems to post the token just fine. Is it just that you don't know what to do with it once posted?

Comment: I just wanted to show you how I would do it with AJAX. although still lacking quite a bit, maybe this would help: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f70266cfa18e986ae2f19295fc7f4074